# How to set the 'name' of an agenda file

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have several agenda files which have the same filename (but are from different directories).  This is because I'm using a uniform template for all my projects, which include, e.g., a `$PRJHOME/README.org` file.

Currently, when I do `C-c a a`, this leads to all entries from any of the projects' `README.org` files to have the "label" `README`.

How can I set the individual `README.org`'s "label" inside the `README.org` file?  There must be some property to do this, but I couldn't find anything ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "label" that appears in the agenda is actually the [category](http://orgmode.org/manual/Categories.html), which is set by `CATEGORY` [property](http://orgmode.org/manual/Properties-and-Columns.html). It defaults to the file name if `CATEGORY` isn't set.  You can set this for the entire file by adding a line `#+CATEGORY: MyCategory` to the file.  Do `C-c C-c` on that line or close/reopen the file to make it take effect.

This property can also be set on individual entries using `org-set-property` (`C-c C-x p`).  Unlike most properties, `CATEGORY` is inherited so setting on one item will also set the category of all that items children.